# how do I configure my staticfiles in django?

Tags: python, django, django-staticfiles

I followed the procedures to setup staticfiles but I'm not getting what i want
[image: settings.py]

when I add an image to the section background it gives a wrong path "staticfiles/css/assets/img/oilcarriage.jpg"
[image: register.css]

instead of "staticfiles/assets/img/oilcarriage.jpg"
here's the path to the image:
[image: path to the image]

i would be really grateful if you can help me now :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to join the path so use the following `STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles'),)`

Comment: it's actually a django 3.9 version and the BASE_DIR IS "Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent" not "os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))"

Answer (score 0):

Here you go static file config in settings.py file

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
]
```

Comment: it's actually a django 3.9 version and the BASE_DIR IS "Path(file).resolve().parent.parent" not "os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(file)))"

Comment: It's a same thing, we can try it. make sure your static folder in the base dir